# Как создать директорию в android?

Tags: java, android

У меня возникла проблема, при создании директории не возникает исключение, но директория не создается, разрешения все подключены. Тестирую программу на Android 10. Код программы:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    boolean checkPermission = canWriteToExternalStorage(getApplicationContext());
    String str= String.valueOf(checkPermission);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Sample Directory");

    if(!file.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),str,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private static boolean canWriteToExternalStorage(Context context) {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Comment: Android studio - это среда разработки, чтобы код удобнее писать. Если с ее помощью и создавать директории, то они будут на вашем компьютере. Не надо путать средство  (редактор кода) и продукт (программа , выполняющая какие то функции).

Comment: Не создаётся потому что нет разрешения на запись - вы только проверяете выдано ли оно, но не запрашиваете у пользователя. Кое-какой пример и объяснение есть в доках: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#make-the-request .

Comment: @pavlofff запускал программу на устройстве.

Comment: С 9, вроде версии ОС просто так создать файл вне папки приложения не получится. Читайте доку по этому поводу. Если же вам не надо именно в общедоступной памяти файл создавать, то и разрешение на запись не нужно.